# Does the Broker innocent increase Bonus HL rewards?

Tags: disgaea-4

If I have the Broker Innocent on my weapons or armor do I only get boosted HL from killing enemies or do I get a boost across all HL earnings?

Answer (score 1):

The Broker Innocent only increases the amount of HL you get from defeating enemies.

Comment: Could you perhaps links a source for this fact? Perhaps confirmation from a game wiki or a guide/FAQ?